# Quadratic Diophantine Equation $x^2 + 2y^2 = 2013$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

Find integer values of $x$ and $y$ (if any) such that $x^2 + 2y^2 = 2013$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The equation is not solvable modulo $8$, hence there are no integer solutions.

You can see this by considering $x^2\equiv 0,1$ or $4$ modulo $8$ for every $x$.